# How do you impersonate a Windows virtual account using C++ and WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, impersonation

I am currently working on modifying some security practices for an application and was looking for any guidance on impersonating Windows virtual account.

I have an application right now that forces UAC to run as an admin, but I want to make it start using a different user after that point to essentially take away some privileges. I already have a virtual account setup for another process we own that is already configured with the right access rights and whatnot we need, but I can't seem to find any good Microsoft documentation for how this would be done.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
HANDLE hUser;
LogonUser(L"AccountName", L"NT SERVICE", NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hUser);

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(&hUser);
```

but when I do I get an error from `LogonUser` - ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE. It almost looks like it can't see the virtual account? I know there is also a flag that can be used instead of LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT that is LOGON32_PROVIDER_VIRTUAL, but when I use that I get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER instead.

Any direction to useful docs/examples would be great, as I would really like to avoid having to manually grab the token of the application and setting all the permissions by hand if possible.

Comment: whats a'virtual account'?

Comment: note this for LOGON SERVICE "Indicates a service-type logon. The account provided must have the service privilege enabled."

Comment: For virtual account, see https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/managed-service-accounts-msa-and-virtual-accounts

But I do have the service privilege enabled I believe already

Comment: To login as `NT SERVICE` the account calling `LogonUser` must have the security permission to logon as a service in the system's security policy

Comment: Both the user that is initially running the application, and the user I am trying to run as have the `SeServiceLogonRight` permissions, and I can see them in the GPO so I think that is setup properly already

Comment: These type services aren't well documented and for this goal. It's recommended to use normal accounts.